# How to a convert a list to a slightly different one using "map"?

Tags: elixir

Say I have a List:

```
my_list = [age: {"is invalid", []}, name: {"can't be blank", []}]
```

I can't figure out how to convert it to something like this:

```
[age: "is invalid", name: "can't be blank"]
```

I have to use Enum.map, but how exactly should I convert one to another?

```
 Enum.map(my_list, fn(a) -> ???? end)
```

Note that the names of the keys aren't known in compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this function: `fn {field, {reason, _}} -> {field, reason} end` with `Enum.map/2`:

```
iex(1)> my_list = [age: {"is invalid", []}, name: {"can't be blank", []}]
[age: {"is invalid", []}, name: {"can't be blank", []}]
iex(2)> Enum.map(my_list, fn {field, {reason, _}} -> {field, reason} end)
[age: "is invalid", name: "can't be blank"]
```

You can also use `for`:

```
iex(3)> for {field, {reason, _}} <- my_list, do: {field, reason}
[age: "is invalid", name: "can't be blank"]
```

Comment: You could also try to use `elem/2` but using pattern matching is obviously mor readable.